# CSS backdrop-filter for only the border and blurred border

Tags: html, css, border, blur

I am trying to achieve certain effects involving `backdrop-filter` and the border of elements. It is simple enough to create an element that blurs the elements behind it. However, I can't figure out how to only let the `backdrop-filter` affect the border area of the element.

[image]
The above Effect is possible with CSS. However, is it possible to get the following effects:

- A blurred backdrop of the element, and the border brightening the backdrop. From my attempts, applying `backdrop-filter` affects the element's box only, not that of its children (e.g. adding a border only serves to make the filtered area bigger). example below
  [image]
- A blurred element with a backdrop filter, for example below
  [image]
- A blurred border with a backdrop filter, for example below
  [image]

Slightly unrelated, is it possible to have the background be clipped using the border of an element? [image] like below I have tried using clip-path, but I can't seem to figure out how to get a rounded bounding area.

I suspect that most of these effects are not possible currently, as the backdrop filter applies only to the given element, and can't be stacked with child elements.

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. please take the tour first. Then read [how to ask questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After that edit the question to meet the guidelines and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for debugging details. Pictures with code-lines are inacceptable!!

Answer (score 1):

I was also searching a similar thing and found a useful article [here](https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/). 
You can do some of your example elements with `clipping`. 
Here the

> A blurred element with a backdrop filter

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="170" height="200">
  <defs>
    <filter id="filter">
      <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="5" />
    </filter>
    <mask id="mask">
      <ellipse cx="50%" cy="50%" rx="25%" ry="25%" fill="white" filter="url(#filter)"></ellipse>
    </mask>
  </defs>

  <image xlink:href="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/Harry-Potter-1-.jpg" width="170" height="200" mask="url(#mask)" style="filter: blur(2px)"></image>
</svg>
```