# How to apply blurness to css borders

Tags: css

```
.homepage .home-bottom-overlay .overlay::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 100%;
    border-width: 42.5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: transparent rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) transparent;
    backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
}
```

Hey community I want to apply blurness in the background of this angle but the blurness is working with this.

Comment: Can you rephrase the question, it does not make any sense to me.

Comment: I have to make a right angle triangle by using CSS and in the background I have apply some blurness.

Comment: What is the background? Is the border blurred? What is blurred?

Answer (score 1):

looks like you want a blurred border.

for border blur, you can use `box-shadow: x y blur spread;`

```css
.box{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  box-shadow:0px 0px 10px 0px #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

you can learn more about that [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-shadow.asp)

Answer (score 0):

I think OP need the backdrop apply only on the border, not the whole `::before` pseudo element.

If I understand correctly, this is duplicate to [CSS backdrop-filter for only the border, and blurred border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68873988/css-backdrop-filter-for-only-the-border-and-blurred-border) . And it might not be possible to set backdrop for the border, it's applied to the whole element (which is a rectangle instead of triangle). You can make use of SVG to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code :

HTML

```
<div></div>
```

CSS

```
$url: url(http://codeskulptor-demos.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/GalaxyInvaders/back04.jpg);
$b: 1.1em; // border-width
$blur: blur(9px);
$rect: inset(0);

div {
    position: relative;
    border: solid $b rgba(#000, .03);
    height: 50vmin;
    max-width: 12em;
    max-height: 6em;
    background: $url 50%/ cover border-box  padding-box ;
    font-size: 2em;
    
    &:before {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: -1; /* put it *behind* parent */
        /* go outside padding-box by 
         * a border-width ($b) in every direction */
        top: -$b; right: -$b; bottom: -$b; left: -$b;
        border: inherit;
        border-color: transparent;
        background: inherit;
        background-clip: border-box;
        -webkit-filter: $blur;
                        filter: $blur;

        -webkit-clip-path: $rect;
                        clip-path: $rect;
        content: ''
    }
}
```

[image]